# Как изменить язык админки сайта на WordPress(установлен на русском языке) с русского на украинский?

Tags: wordpress

Добавил в файл wp-config.php

```
define ('WPLANG', 'uk_UA');
```

в общих настройках в выпадающем списке появился язык uk_UA
если его выбрать админка переключается на английский

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Settings** -> **General** -> **Site Language** и выбрать нужный язык.

После сохранения подтянется нужный перевод сайта.

Установите также язык в своём профиле пользователя. Или украинский, или "язык сайта по умолчанию".

Строка в `wp-config.php` совсем не нужна.

Comment: Ты уточни, чтобы он в профиле пользователя поставил язык сайта. У него небось там английский. А строка в wp-config вообще не нужна

Comment: Изначально в выпадающем списке Язык сайта были Английский и Русский. после добавления указанного выше кода в этом списке добавился язык - uk_UA. если я переключаюсь на него язык сайта становиться - английским.

Comment: @KirillDonenko вы прочитали, что я тут написал? В профиль пользователя посмотрели?

Comment: в профиле пользователя ( я - админ) есть только английский и русский

Comment: У меня нет этой константы на сайте и все языки доступны

Comment: Так не бывает - обновите страницу профиля. И поставьте там "язык сайта"

Comment: страницу обновил, кеш почистил. но в выпадающем списке только два языка. скрин сделать не могу

Comment: Какая версия wp?

Comment: Да у него небось Polylang какой-нибудь стоит. Ну не бывает так.

Comment: @KirillDonenko если ответ решил вашу проблему отметьте его галочкой)

Comment: Версия 5.3.2 никаких плагинов перевода нет

Comment: @Krya вопрос не решен ((((

Comment: Пришлите скрин админки

Comment: Как вставить сюда скрин с мобильного?

Comment: Вставьте его в ваш вопрос, в комментарии нельзя добавить скрины)

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/JcFQFu7GTrrUAFCq8

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/swACEe1CJUAqZwFR9

Comment: проверил на другом сайте. в выпадающем списке у пользователя есть - Основной язык сайта, английский и русский. Если я переключаюсь на английский, то админка отображается на английском. в основных настройках в выпадающем списке есть полный список доступных языков, но когда выбираю - украинский и сохраняю, автоматом переключается на русский.

Comment: @KirillDonenko давай ещё я пробую донести слова коллег: язык сайта и язык пользователя можно настраивать по отдельности. И именно это тебе надо сделать. А строка в конфиге давно не нужна. 2-е: основной язык может быть только один. На то он и основной. 3е: язык на фронте зависит от наличия лангпака темы и плагов.  А ланпак ВП, (если вдруг укр. так и не появился в бекенде, что возможно на криво настроенном сервере) ты можешь скачать самостоятельно отсюда https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/uk/default/wp/dev/